# How to correctly add the returned variable as an argument to selenium Options() in this python program?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

This program will ask the user for the `Profile Path` of Chrome Browser, for then adding that path as an argument to selenium options in the statement `opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+f"r'{x}'")`:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk #for user inputs
from tkinter import messagebox #for warning messages 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400') #resolution
root.title("Bulkdozer") #Name of this program
root.attributes('-topmost', True) #keep the program's window top-most

x = ""
def submit_profile_path():
    if len(profile_path.get()) == 0: #check if the user didn't type anything and pressed the button 
        messagebox.showerror(message="You didn't provide any input, try again", title="NULL Input")
    elif len(profile_path.get()) > 0:
        if r'\Google\Chrome\User Data' in profile_path.get(): #check if the path provided by the user is a valid one
            if profile_path.get().split("User Data\\",1)[1] != "": #now check if at the end of that path exist an actual profile folder
                user_data.pack_forget() #hide the user_data button
                data_input.pack_forget() #hide the data_input
                profile_path_label.pack_forget() #hide the profile_path_label
                open_browser.pack() #show the open_browser button
                global x
                x = profile_path.get()
                return x
                
            else: #inform the user that he must provide the profile path containing the corresponding profile folder
                messagebox.showwarning(message="You forgot to add the PROFILE FOLDER in the profile path, try again", title="Profile Folder Missing")
                data_input.delete(0, tk.END)        
                
        else: #inform the user that he must provide a valid profile path
            messagebox.showwarning(message="The path provided does not seem to be the right one, try again", title="Invalid Profile PATH")
            data_input.delete(0, tk.END)
            
# BUTTON FOR PROVIDING THE PROFILE PATH OF CHROME BROWSER #
profile_path = tk.StringVar() #This variable will be used for storing the profile path string passed by the user
signin = ttk.Frame(root) #create a container for the profile_path variable
signin.pack(padx=55, pady=20, fill='x', expand=True) #define the dimensional measurement and location for this container
profile_path_label = ttk.Label(signin, text="Introduce YOUR profile path:") #create a label for the profile_path variable
profile_path_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True) #add the label
data_input = ttk.Entry(signin, textvariable=profile_path) #create an entry for the profile_path variable
data_input.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
data_input.focus()
user_data = tk.Button(root, width=20,  text="Submit User Data", command=submit_profile_path) #executes the function when clicked
user_data.place(x=60, y=40, width=100, height=30) #define the dimensional measurement and location for this button
user_data.pack() #Apply The Pack geometry manager to this button for using its functions later on


opt = Options() #selenium options
opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+f"r'{x}'") #PATH profile
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Profile to use
s = Service('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

########################     BUTTON ZONE     #############################

def open_chrome_profile():
    #webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://opensea.io/asset/create') #open a new tab using user's default browser
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
    driver.get('https://opensea.io/login?referrer=%2Faccount')

# BUTTON FOR OPENING A CHROME DRIVER WITH THE OPTIONS PASSED #

open_browser = tk.Button(root, width=20,  text="Open OpenSea Tab", command=open_chrome_profile) #executes the function when clicked
open_browser.place(width=100, height=30) #define the dimensional measurement and location for this button
open_browser.pack() #Apply The Pack geometry manager to this button for using its functions later on
open_browser.pack_forget() #initialize this button hidden

######################     BUTTON ZONE END     ###########################
root.mainloop()
```

However, after compiling this program and pressing the `open_browser` button it generates the following error:

> Google Chrome can't read nor add data to data directory: r''

I thought that by assigning the value of `profile_path.get()` to the global `x` variable and returning it, the program could effectively call the updated `x` in `opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+f"r'{x}'")` for then executing a chrome driver with the corresponding user data, but it did not.

I must also recognize that I'm not sure if this statement `f"r'{x}'"` is actually doing what I'm thinking it is doing, so I come here to ask for a feedback about how the profile path provided by the user in this program could effectively be added as an argument to selenium options after executing `submit_profile_path()`.

Comment: Side note: You might need `rf'{x}'` and not `f"r'{x}'"` but why do you need `f` at all? Something like `r'{}'.format(x)` can work or maybe even `x.encode('unicode_escape')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried all of them and none worked :(, with the last option you suggested I tried `opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+x.encode('unicode_escape'))` and got the following error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`

Comment: Yea I did not take that context into account. What does `print(x)` give

Comment: it prints `C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` which is my current `Profile Path`

Comment: Might be some other issue, you can wait for an explanation from someone else

Comment: I tried ```fr'--user-data-dir="{x}"'``` and got a new error: ```selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at "" is still attached to a running Chrome or Chromium process``` which means that in this case the `x` variable does not seem to be returning the right path ```C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default```, do you know what can be causing the issue this time? I think I'm closer to the solution, and I didn't have chrome browser opened btw @CoolCloud